# vscode pylint on all project files without opening them

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm looking for a solution to run pylint in vscode on all files of my project without need to open them (like checkstyle in eclipse on Java).

Thank you.

Comment: I was also hoping for this but haven't been able to find any way to achieve it in Visual Studio Code. This issue / feature request seems relevant https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13953

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doing this is currently not possible (see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/82).

Fortunately you can achieve a similar thing using vscode tasks (see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/82).

```
{
    "label": "pylint: whole project",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": ".venv/bin/pylint --msg-template \"{path}:{line}:{column}:{category}:{symbol} - {msg}\" mycloud",
    "windows": {
        "command": ".venv/Scripts/pylint --msg-template \"{path}:{line}: {column}:{category}:{symbol} - {msg}\" mycloud"
    },
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "never",
        "panel": "shared"
    },
    "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "python",
        "fileLocation": [
            "relative",
            "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.+):(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\w+):(.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

You have also the Tab Problem in Terminal which will show all files with problems.
(You need Php Intelephense or similar Extension for other language)
[image]